# ResultSet first não funciona

Tags: java, sql, resultset

Estou criando uma aplicação em Java no Eclipse.

Estou com problemas para fazer os botões Primeiro, Anterior, Próximo e Último funcionarem.

Estou preso no botão Primeiro, pois, acredito eu, que a diferença seja apenas o `.first()`, `.next()`, `.previous()` e `.last()`.

O erro que aparece quando clico no botão é esse:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operação inválida para encaminhar apenas
>   conjunto de resultados : first

A tabela `Aluno` possui os campos `ra` e `nome`, ambos são `varchar2`.

Quando eu clicar no botão Primeiro vai ativar esse método:

```
public void primeiro() {
    try {
        //con é meu objeto da classe ConexaoMVC
        con.conecta();

        ResultSet rs;
        String RA,NOME;

        rs = con.stm.executeQuery("Select * from Aluno");
        rs.first();

        RA = rs.getString("ra");
        NOME = rs.getString("nome");
        // visao é o objeto da minha classe de interface grafica
        visao.setRA(RA);
        visao.setNome(NOME);

    } catch(SQLException SqlExc){ //trata os erros
        System.out.println("Erro de SQL! \n"+SqlExc);      
    }
}
```

Código da minha classe conexão:

```
package bd;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ConexaoMVC {
    public Connection conexao;
    private String driver, url;
    Statement stm;

    public ConexaoMVC() {
        //driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:guilherme/1997@//localhost:1521/XE";
    }

    public void conecta() {
        try {
            // carrega o driver da ponte jdbc-odbc
            Class.forName(driver);
            // abre conexao com o banco de dados
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Conexão executada com sucesso");

            stm = conexao.createStatement();
            //conexao.close();
        } catch (SQLException SqlExc) {
            System.out.println("Erro de SQL!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException exc) {
            System.out.println("Classe não encontrada!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Conexao ins = new Conexao();
    }
}
```

Código dos Sets:

```
public void setRA(String ra) {
    jtfRa.setText(ra);
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    jtfNome.setText(nome);
}
```

Comment: Sei que funcionou, pois criei um println e o resultado saiu certo. Mas não está aparecendo nos meus JTextFields, editei a pergunta e adicionei meus métodos set, você poderia dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SQLException: Operação inválida para encaminhar apenas conjunto de resultados: `first`

Isso acontece porque por padrão o [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) não é atualizável, e o *cursor* somente avança, não retrocede.

Se não passar argumentos para [`Connection.html#createStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement--), é assumido que o tipo do `ResultSet` será [`TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY), cujo *cursor* pode mover-se somente para frente, e o nível de concorrência [`CONCUR_READ_ONLY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#CONCUR_READ_ONLY), que indica que  o `ResultSet` não pode ser atualizável.

Não é permitido os métodos [`first`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first--), [`last`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last--), [`previous`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#previous--), [`absolute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute-int-) ou [`relative`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#relative-int-).

No [`Connection.html#createStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement-int-int-), você pode mudar esse comportamento, faça assim:

```
stm = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
```

Ao indicar o tipo [`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE), você pode mover o *cursor* do `ResultSet` para onde desejar, usando os métodos citados acima.

Se você quiser que o `ResultSet` seja atualizável, indique o nível de concorrência [`CONCUR_UPDATABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#CONCUR_UPDATABLE):

```
stm = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                              ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```